# Images not being loaded

Tags: wordpress, magento

I have transferred magento installation from one server to another. Everything running smoothly but my magento wordpress integration doesn't show my images in the blog. I checked the source code and it says failed to load images whereas images are there, even i tried loading new post but images in media uploader (thumbnails) doesn't show up and when click insert it shows a broken image icon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following MySQL queries need to be run to change the domain names for WordPress in its database (if my assumption of the domain name being different is correct)

```
UPDATE wp_posts set post_content=REPLACE(post_content, 'old-domain.com', 'new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value= replace(meta_value, 'old-domain.com', 'new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old-domain.com', 'new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Comment: the only old url i found in wp_posts where under guid because when i ran your commands the output was zero row effected. what is guid? is it because of that.How can i run command of db to check if any value in whole db is given my old url? also in source code the url of images are of current server not previous.

Comment: [this](http://screencast.com/t/YDlFn0thfw) is how the media uploader shows but i checked folder and images are it in.

Comment: any help? did u look at the website?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of your media folder where wp images are stored. It should be readable if not make is 644, also try 777 if 644 doesn't work